# Triggering form's submit event manually in React doesn't check required inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to find a way to trigger the submit event manually, just like a button with type="submit" would.
I found a way to do that, from another post here, but unfortunately it doesn't check if the required inputs contain values and submits the form even when no text was typed into the input:

https://codesandbox.io/s/q92855nz3w

or

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("A name was submitted: " + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div onClick={this.handleSubmit}>SOME DIV</div>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            required
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

render(<NameForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Clicking on the button checks the textfield and gives an error if it's empty, clicking on "Some Div" doesn't check the input and submits the form even when the input is empty.

Comment: Calling handleSubmit on div isn’t required. You should remove that. Your code looks fine then. The code in sandbox works as well

Comment: The problem is clicking the button and the div does two different things. Try typing nothing into the field and clicking the button, a required message pops up. Clicking the div submits the form and an alert pops up.

Comment: can you move validation outside of html, into `handleSubmit`?

Comment: Yes,  that would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to my question:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.reportValidity();
```